# Different style of filling in x direction

Tags: filling

I have the following curves:

```
linea = Line[{{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 50}}]; Show[
Plot[{2/Abs[a], 3/Abs[a], 4/Abs[a], 6/Abs[a]}, {a, 0, 1}, 
Mesh -> {{0.1, 1}}, MeshShading -> {Dashed, Automatic, Dotted}, 
MeshStyle -> None, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, 
Ticks -> {{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}, 
Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
Epilog -> {Directive[Black, DotDashed], PointSize[.015], linea}]]
```

I would like to plot filling option with two different styles: for `0 < a < 1` light grey, for `a>1` grey. How can I obtain this option?
Moreover, how can I grow up the size of dash in `DotDashed` style of `linea`?
Thank you

Comment: try `Dashing[{0, Small, Large, Small}]` in place of `DotDashed`.

Comment: you probably meant "for `0 < a < 0.1` light grey,..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[{1, 1, 2, 3, 4}]];
linea = Line[{{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 50}}]; 
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[2/Abs[a], a <= .1], 
  ConditionalExpression[2/Abs[a], a >= .1], 3/Abs[a], 4/Abs[a], 6/Abs[a]}, {a, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.1, 1}}, MeshShading -> {Dashed, Automatic, Dotted}, MeshStyle -> None, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, LightGray}, 2 -> {Axis, LightBlue}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Thickness[.005]]], 
 Ticks -> {{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1},  Automatic}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Dashing[{0, Small, Large, Small}]], PointSize[.015], linea}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! how can I specify colors in "colors"?

Comment: @GaeP, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. You can set `colors` to your choice, e.g., `colors  = { Red, Red, Green, Blue, Orange}`.

Comment: I would like to use the default color...how can i do this?

Comment: @GaeP, for default color in versions 10+  use  `colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[{1, 1, 2, 3, 4}]];`

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to complete Epilog section:  

    Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Thick, Dashing[{0, Small, Large, 
    Small}]],
    linea, Inset[
    Framed[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(22\)]\)", 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 13], 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin, Dashed]], {.15, 6}], 
    Inset[Framed[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(nn\)]\)", 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 13], 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin, Dashed]], {.4, 
    25}]}]]

but FrameStyle doesn't work...Mathematica 10.0

Comment: @GaeP,  looks like it works in version 11. But in version 9 (it seems in version 10 too) `FrameStyle`  option in `Framed` does not handle dashing and thickness. You might want to post this as a new question.